# Where CultureInfo Coming From?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to change my current Culture info.
In my Code : 
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name 
returns "en-US"

Where it is coming from..?
i want "zh-CN" as Culture name ... where to set?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) property, for current thread try:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
```

Comment: Thanks But !!,

i Need to Get " zh-CN " automatically....
In my code ,CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name giving "en-US" automatically 
without 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
so how to get "zh-CN"
Please Help

Comment: @Britman, you can go to your computer's `Control Panel`, go to `Region and Language`, there select Format 'Chinese Simplified, PRC` and you will get `zh-CN` culture by default in your application. Your culture info comes from the computer using the application